# Stop automatic submit on jquery.filer plugin when using AJAX

Tags: jquery

When using the **jquery.filer** plugin, is there a way of stopping the automatic upload when using AJAX?

I only want the files to upload on submit.

I have tried setting "addMore" to true, but the files get instantly uploaded.

Code snippet below:

```
$('input').filer({
    uploadFile: {
        url: 'upload.php',
        data: site.underscoreArrayKeys($(this).data()),
        type: 'POST',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set `uploadFile` option on `null` to disable instant uploading. Instead use a normal `<form>` with submit button.